# How to use two function that update same state with useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, api, use-effect, use-state

Im trying to make a hook that do two queries to api and then save the result in the state like this:

```
   const useQueryApiInfo = ():UseQueryType=>{
    const [state, setState] = useState<stateType>({data:null, error:null, loading:false})
    const CURRENT_LOGGED_IN_USER_NAME = getLoggedInUserName();
    
    // for getApiIdeaInfo query
    const GetApiIdeaInfo:GetApiIdeaInfoType =async(authState, id, CURRENT_LOGGED_IN_USER_NAME)=>{
        const res = await getApiIdeaInfo(authState, id, CURRENT_LOGGED_IN_USER_NAME)
        if (res.errors) { setState({ ...state, error: res.errors, loading: false, data: null }) }
        if (!res.data) return;
        setState({ data:{...state.data?.resFromFetchProposal,resFromApiInfo:res.data.getApiIdeaFullInfo}, error:null, loading:false})
        console.log(state,"from getIdea")
    }
    
    // for fetchProposal mutation
    
    const FetchProposalsForIdea =async(id:string)=>{
        const res = await fetchProposalsForIdea(id)
        if (res.errors) { setState({ ...state, error: res.errors, loading: false, data: null }) }
        if (!res.data) return;
        setState({  data:{...state.data?.resFromApiInfo, resFromFetchProposal:res.data?.fetchProposalsForAnIdea}, error:null, loading:false})
        
    }
    return [state, {GetApiIdeaInfo, FetchProposalsForIdea, ReactOnApiIdea}]

}
```

iam calling this function in useEffect like this:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        updateApiInfo.GetApiIdeaInfo(CURRENT_AUTH_STATE,productId,CURRENT_LOGGED_IN_USER_NAME)
         updateApiInfo.FetchProposalsForIdea(productId)
    },[])
```

but the problem is It is updating only the last state. it is not giving the result of both queries. what Iam doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
setState((prevState) => {  
   return {
     ...prevState,
     data: {
       ...prevState.data,
       resFromFetchProposal: res.data?.fetchProposalsForAnIdea
     },
     error:null, loading:false
   }
})
```

```js
setState((prevState) => {  
   return {
     ...prevState,
     data: {
       ...prevState.data,
       resFromApiInfo: res.data?.getApiIdeaFullInfo
     },
     error:null, loading:false
   }
})
```